# Latitude, Longitude in SSAS

Tags: powerbi, ssas, latitude-longitude, live, sqldatatypes

How can I create data type Latitude and Longitude in SSAS?
I want Latitude, Longitude in live connection power BI, but in live connection, I can't change varchar to geography (Latitude, Longitude)!

I want Latitude, Longitude in live connection power BI, but in live connection, I can't change varchar to geography (Latitude, Longitude)!

Comment: It's not possible in live connection to change datatype, you can instead change the datatype in SSAS

Comment: Thank you for answering .How can I change datatype in SSAS ?

Comment: You can follow these steps [Set the Data Type of a Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/set-the-data-type-of-a-column-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions)